# Using or omitting of "as"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Are we born with sense of morality, or do we arrive blank slates
>   waiting for the world to teach us right from wrong? Or could it be
>   worse, do we start out nasty selfish devils... ([Source](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/born-good-babies-help-unlock-the-origins-of-morality/))

Do we need "as" in these sentences above as shown below? Is the original one complete as is?

> Are we born with sense of morality, or do we arrive ***as*** blank
>   slates waiting for the world to teach us right from wrong? Or could it
>   be worse, do we start out ***as*** nasty selfish devils...

Answer (score 2):

The "as" is optional in both sentences, but the first one especially seems awkward without it. Personally I would use it in both sentences.

Comment: What about "being", would you use "being" in the place of "as" here? "...we arrive being blank slates..."

Comment: @Talha I think that's correct. Personally I wouldn't use it for the first sentence.