# In what cases can I omit 'as' after 'marked'?

Tags: verbs, as, prepositional-verbs

The context is *software*, as in:

> "fields marked **as** optional",
> "properties marked **as** private",
> etc.

I saw people sometimes don't use **'as'** in such phrases. Is there a rule to omit **'as'**?

Comment: I think this is quite a minor difference. The *as* could be seen as providing a small amount of extra clarity (mainly for non-native speakers, perhaps?), but there's not much difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using or omitting of "as"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222881/using-or-omitting-of-as)

Answer (score 2):

One could certainly write:

> Properties marked private include owner and address.

In this case it may help to think of "private" as a caption for the property. when the term is more of a description the use of "as" may flow better. For example:

> Fields marked as "password entry" are shown with asterisks in place of character content.

In general the use or omission of "as" in this construct is a matter of style, and will not change the meaning.